# Excluding Multiple OU's for Get-ADUser Results with Parameters

Tags: powershell

I'm Pretty new to Powershell so be kind :).

I'm trying to export AD Users from a specific OU that don't have a manager assigned and excluding multiple Sub-OUs from the results.
The end results are exported to CSV in the end.
My Code:

```
        param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$OUPath,
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    # The OUs that you want to exclude from the query
    [String[]]$OUPathExclude,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    # Output Path of the CSV
    [String]$FilePath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    # Name Of the File
    [String]$FileName
    
    )

Get-ADUser -Properties manager -filter * -SearchBase $OUPath | 
select Name, 
    @{label='User Name';Expression='SamAccountName'}, 
    @{Label='Manager Name';Expression={(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.manager | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)}},
    DistinguishedName |
    Where-Object {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*,'+$OUPathExclude) -AND ($_.'Manager Name' -eq $null)} |
sort -Property name -CaseSensitive
Export-Csv -Path $FilePath\$FileName.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

So when removing '[]' in [String[]]$OUPathExclude parameter it accepts the one OU i'm excluding and it's working great, but when putting back '[]' it doesn't accepts the multiple OU in the where-object CmdLet although when entering the variable you can see the 2 OUs being input into the vairable.
also, tried the 2 versions of foreach but didn't seem to get it working.

the tool is designed to feet a team that is not so technical so i don't want to convert it to a CmdLet throgh function and commandlet binding, and i also don't want to stupidly put multiple variables in the script and let them change him each time.

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions by building the exclusion pattern with each value separated by `|` which is the *alternation (or)* operator and changing `-notlike` to `-notmatch`

Should be in this format

```
'OUDN1|OUDN2|OUDN3'
```

Simply build it with a `-join` statement. It will only add the character when there is more than one value.

```
$OUPathExclude = $OUPathExclude -join '|'
```

and

```
$_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $OUPathExclude
```

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you for the quick response, but unfortunately it doesn't work with the code you suggested. it's doesn't even exclude the first OU...

Answer (score 0):

The code can be more efficient if you filter out any users that do not have a `manager` property filled in straight away. There are more ways to do this of course. The code below uses `-LDAPFilter "(manager=*)"`

Then to exclude users in certain OU paths, you can build a regex string to check for that:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$OUPath,
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    # The OUs that you want to exclude from the query
    [String[]]$OUPathExclude,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    # Output Path of the CSV
    [String]$FilePath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    # Name Of the File
    [String]$FileName
)

# build a regex string to match the OU's to exclude
# use [regex]::Escape() to escape all characters that have special meaning in regex
# join the results of that with the regex OR character '|'
# the dollar sign anchors the match to the end of the OU string
$excludeThese = '({0})$' -f (($OUPathExclude | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|')

$result = Get-ADUser -Properties manager -LDAPFilter "(manager=*)" -SearchBase $OUPath | 
          Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $excludeThese } | 
          Select-Object Name, 
                        @{label='User Name';Expression= $_.SamAccountName }, 
                        @{Label='Manager Name';Expression={(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.manager).Name}},
                        DistinguishedName |
          Sort-Object -Property Name -CaseSensitive

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path -Path $FilePath -ChildPath ('{0}.csv' -f $FileName)) -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Should the user name expression reference $_.samAccountName?

Answer (score 0):

So One of my teammates helped me and it seems to work great.
here is the code for reference:

```
    param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$OUPath,
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String[]]$OUPathExclude,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$FilePath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$FileName
    
    )

$script = "
Get-ADUser -Properties manager -filter *  -SearchBase '" + [string]$OUPath +"' | select Name, 
    @{label='User Name';Expression='SamAccountName'},
    @{Label='Manager Name';Expression={(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.manager | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)}},
    DistinguishedName |
    Where-Object {"
foreach ($ou in $OUPathExclude)
{
 $script= $script + ' ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike ''*,''+'''+$ou+''') -AND'
}

$script =$script + ' ($_.''Manager Name'' -eq $null)} |
sort -Property name -CaseSensitive '
$script

Invoke-Expression $script| Export-Csv -Path $FilePath\$FileName.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Why mangle code into a string in such an awful way and then execute it with Invoke-Expression where you can simply write the code??